# Remove special character string from R

Tags: r, special-characters, tm

Trying to run `tm` on R and I can't get rid of `â€“` as a string. I've tried `"â€“`,`"â€\“"`, `'â€“'`.  Trying to include string in `myStopwords <- c("issu","base","...")`

Answer (score 0):

Try `gsub` function to replace characters except printable characters: `[:alnum:]`, `[:punct:]` and `space`
`gsub("[^[:print:]]"," ",text)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsub` to remove specific word:

```
string ="â€“ test â€“ data â€“" # This is your sample input
gsub("â€“","",string)  # Remove â€ from your string
```

Output:

```
[1] " test  data "
```

Comment: Thanks...but the string is  3 characters:  â€“

Comment: Its the  “ that I'm having the problem with I think

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to remove it from my Corpus named docs. I previously tried. str_replace_all(docs, "[^[:alnum:]]", " ")